# Calculate the next date based on frequency in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to populate a column with the next "billing date" based on another column "frequency" and "Date of Bill"
I have already used simple calculation and used it to get the billing date.
But the problem is , that some billing dates are in the past because the "Date of Bill" is more than a year ago and the frequency is 1 month.
Below is an example:

[image: As it is now]

But I would like to get the billing date as the upcoming billing as it is in monthly bills.

[image: How i would like it to be]

As of now im calulating Billing date, as below.

```
result = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    result.append(row["CUSTOM FIELD (DATE OF BILL)"]+relativedelta(months=+row['BillingFrequency']))
df['BillingDate']=result
```

Can someone please let me know how to get the dates?

Comment: I cant paste any screenshots. But the below answer has helped. Thanks